# How to pull data from database after logging into vb.net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, authentication

I'm currently creating a vb.net application and i found a tutorial to create a log in script, the code of which is as follows:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnection.MyConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from [customer_login] where username='" + tbUsename.Text + "' and password='" + tbPassword.Text + "'", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            Dim 
            MsgBox("you are logged on as " + tbUsename.Text)
            TabControl1.SelectedTab = tabDetails
        End If
    End Sub
```

Though i'll be the first to admit i still don't have a full understanding of how this code works... But anyway i'd now like use this logged in state to pull relevant data (such as the users name and address etc.) from my sql server database to autocomplete textboxes in the next window. I'm sure this is possible, and i'm sure it's pretty simple but i cant seem to figure it out. Can anyone explain this to me or point me to a suitable tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty much any tutorial on ASP.NET is going to involve using a database.  Have you tried anything at all?  Also, wherever you found this code, don't use it.  This is wide open to SQL injection.  Any user can execute any code they want on your database through this code.  (Among other problems with this code...)

Comment: ah sorry, believe it or not i did search before posting but i wasn't sure if asp.net was the right thing or what to search :l And it's only for a small project so it's not actually going to go online but i guess it's always good to get into good practices so can you suggest a better tutorial or resource? Thanks

Comment: Did you try the vendor's website?  http://www.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

why you are not to get select again, on dr.read and put into a datatable so you can put your temp data what you want to other form.